# Rectangle Packing - Subset

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I'm working on an algorithm that figures out how to pack rectangles into a larger rectangle. I am aware this is similar to the rectangle packing problem but my particular problem has a few quirks; namely the rectangles that I'm fitting only have a defined height, the width can (and should) vary such that the rectangles that share a vertical overlap with other rectangles will end up having equal widths with respect to the other rectangles they overlap with.

Here is the best formalization I could come up with:

Given a possibly infinite set `R` of real number ranges between `-inf`, `+inf` and an area `A` defined by the points `(0, -inf)`, `(100, +inf)`.

For each range `r` in `R` find a rectangle `Ar` which resides inside area `A` with a height `abs(r1 - r2)` and a width which results in a rectangle that fills as much horizontal space as possible without overlapping any other rectangle.

Here is an image showing an example input set, and the expected output:

[image: Example]

Does anyone have any idea the best way to approach this? I have a somewhat working solution but it fails under conditions where there are a lot of overlapping ranges. Here is the code:

```
val laidOutRectangles = mutableListOf<Rectangle>() // Rectangle is defined by x1, y1, x2, y2
val ranges = mutableListOf<Range>() // Range just has lower and upper bounds
val width = 100

ranges.sortedByDescending { it.first }.forEach { range ->
    // Get top and bottom of range
    val lower = range.first
    val upper = range.second

    // Work out overlapping rectangles
    var overlappingRectangles = 0
    laidOutRectangles.forEach { rectangle ->
        if ((lower >= rectangle.y1 && lower <= rectangle.y2) ||
                (upper >= rectangle.y1 && upper <= rectangle.y2)) {
            overlappingRectangles++
        }
    }

    val rectangleWidth = (width / (overlappingRectangles + 1)).toInt()

    val newRectangle = Rectangle(0, lower, rectangleWidth, upper)
    laidOutRectangles.add(newRectangle)

    var repositionedRectangles = 0
    laidOutRectangles.filter {
        ((lower >= it.y1 && lower <= it.y2) ||
                (upper >= it.y1 && upper <= it.y2))
    }.sortedByDescending {
        Math.abs(upper - lower)
    }.forEach { rectangle ->
        rectangle.width = rectangleWidth
        rectangle.x1 = (rectangleWidth * (repositionedRectangles + 1)).toInt()
        rectangle.x2 = (rectangle.x1 + rectangleWidth)
        repositionedRectangles++
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a restriction missing in the problem description? It's nowhere requested, that the rectangles need to span vertically from r1 to r2 as you have shown in your example.

Comment: Well I do specify the height as `abs(r1 - r2)` in the attempted formalization.

Comment: But that does not specify the location of the rectangle, only its height.

Comment: Ah good point! Yes, the top left most point of the rectangle must have a y component that is equal to r1.

Comment: What is the criteria for the width? Your example shows a rectangle that overlaps with another that doesn't have the same width.